# Strings and the WHERE clause when using RODBC's sqlQuery

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am querying tables in SQL server using RODBC in R:

Example:

```
num = 2
temp <- sqlQuery(conn, sprintf('SELECT "Time", "Temp" 
                                FROM "DataTable" 
                                WHERE "Week_Number" = %s
                                ORDER BY "Time"', num))
```

This works fine, but if I try to use the WHERE clause on a column containing strings I can't get it to work

Example:

```
place_name <- 'London'
temp <- sqlQuery(conn, sprintf('SELECT "Time", "Place" 
                                 FROM "Data_Table" 
                                 WHERE "Place" = %s
                                 ORDER BY "Time"', place_name))
```

I have tried various things e.g:

```
place_name <- 'London'

place_name <- \'London\'

place_name <- "'London'"
place_name <- gsub("'", "''", London)
```

None of this have worked. I am getting the following error message:
"42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'London'."

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried putting the placeholder in double quotes? e.g. `"%s"`?

Comment: Hi @joran, thanks for your suggestion. I did try that and I get the following errors: [1] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name ''London''."  [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT \"Time\" \n                                     FROM \"DataTable\" \n                                     WHERE \"place_name\" = \"'/London'\"\n                                     ORDER BY \"Time\"'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else is interested I found a solution. I installed the RODBCext package, which provides support for parameterized queries. I used the following code:

```
query <- 'SELECT "Time", "Place" FROM "Data_Table" WHERE "Place" = ?'
temp <- sqlExecute(conn, query, 'London', fetch = TRUE)
```

Here is a some good information on the use of RODBCext: [RODBCext](https://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html)